# $M_1$, $M_2$ and $M_1\cap M_2$ injective imply $M_1+M_2$ is also injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, injective-module

> Let $M$ be an $R$-module ($R$ is a ring with identity) and let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be two injective submodules such that $M_1\cap M_2$ is also injective. How to show $M_1+M_2$ is injective?

If the sum $M_1+M_2$ was direct then it's straightforward to show this statement, but in this case I'm a bit lost.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: what exact sequence can you build up out of $M_1\oplus M_2, M_1 + M_2$ and $M_1\cap M_2$?

Comment: I guess the long exact Ext sequence associated to a short one is meant here.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Why need the long exact sequence for Ext to conclude that $M_1+M_2$ is injective when the suggested short exact sequence is split?

Comment: $M$ is injective iff $\mathrm{Ext}^1(-,M)=0$.

Comment: $0\longrightarrow M_1\cap M_2\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} M_1\oplus M_2\stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} M_1+M_2\longrightarrow 0$ where $f(x):=(x, -x)$ and $g(x, y):=x+y$, right?

Comment: @PtF: Sounds good